# GET & POST in RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following RequestMapping I am testing:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/review", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String reviewData( HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, 
        HttpSession session, 
        @RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> data,
        @CurrentUser User user) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

I am testing this code expecting data to be POSTed to it from a vendor's API; which I have confirmed through their documentation andbased on conversations with their developers. Despite this I am receiving a 405 error:

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I am at a lose as to the problem and am open to suggestions. I am actually wonder if the following RequestMapping would work properly to remediate this?

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
```

Comment: yes it will work for both.

Comment: I have seen some seemingly related questions, there are more than one, and none feel like they answer my question; I should have noted that in the description.

Comment: I think you are not correctly POSTing the data. This error message is showing that you are sending a GET request rather than POST.

Comment: How do you test it? maybe you do CORS request that do a preflight GET?

Comment: I have tested it locally using a simple ajax POST and of course it works fine; the problem is that I am testing against a vendor API and I am working with their documentation and vendors and they assure me it is a POST so I am at a lose.